# React mounted component setInterval is not clearing interval due to "state update"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an interval timer set for a function that sets today's date into the state that I initialize in `componenteDidMount`. Although I clear the interval in the `componentWillUnmount`, it still ends up giving an error after quickly switching between components (which is how I caught the bug).

This is the error:

**Warning:** `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.`

I have tried manipulating a private `_isMounted` variable from false to true throughout the cycle and forcing a conditional check in my `setTodaysDate()` prior to setting state, but even that didn't solve the problem.

```
  // _isMounted = false;  <----- tried this method to no avail

  state = {
    selectedDate: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setTodaysDate();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setTodaysDate(), 40 * 1000 * 360);
    // this._isMounted = true;  <----- tried
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    // this._isMounted = false;  <----- tried
  }


  setTodaysDate = () => {
    // if (this._isMounted) {  <----- tried
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: moment(moment(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
        .add(1, "days")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    });

    // }  <----- tried

  }
```

I'm at a loss as to how else to "plug the leak."

**Edit:** It turns out, thanks to Gabriele below, the real cause was a lodash debounce method I was using (where I also setState) that I never cancelled during the unmount, leading to the "leak":

```
  debounceCloseAlert = _.debounce(() => {
    this.setState({ alertVisible: false });
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: You're stating that you use componentWillMount but it's not used. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the issue. The code you posted cannot cause this error.

Comment: thanks, it was typo in what I wrote. the code is exactly as provided.

Comment: Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. I see no chances for this component to cause this error under normal circumstances.

Comment: @estus I just posted a sandbox link at the bottom of my page for the entire component (in RefillComponent). I've had the component and functionality working for over a month, but just caught this during development by accident.

Comment: @Bogie you need to save the sandbox. it is currently empty

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli apologies, fixed.

Comment: The codesandbox doesn't actually run though? There's a bunch of missing deps, and `RefillSearch` isn't called anywhere from index.js. I've added most of the deps to see if it would run, but it's missing `RefillEditModal` and that's your code. I think you need to read up on what an [mcve] is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your component i do not think the issue is with your `setInterval`. The way you handle it is the correct approach and should not produce said error.

The problem i believe is with the use of [`_.debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) in your `debounceCloseAlert` method. It also will create a timeout and you are not clearing that anywhere.

The returned value from `_.debounce` includes a `.cancel()` method to clear the interval. So just call `this.debounceCloseAlert.cancel();` in your `componentWillUnmount` and it will clear it.

Comment: that makes sense, but how would I store the returned value whenever I'm calling the method? I currently call it in two different functions

Comment: Nevermind, I simply turned off the unnecessary debounce call in my toggle method. Another post regarding not using more than one debounce instance per component came to mind. Thanks again Gabrielle!

Comment: @bogie my apologies as well. i did not read the docs completely. You do not need to store anything. The `.cancel` is on the `debounceCloseAlert`. So you just have to add `this.debounceCloseAlert.cancel();` in your `componentWillUnmount` and be done (*and call the `debounceCloseAlert` as many times and from wherever you want*)

Comment: Thanks for this. I also thought `componentWillUnmount` was not clearing the interval properly but it was some other function I used `setTimeout` that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried saving the interval reference in the component's state ?

```
  state = {
    selectedDate: "",
    interval: null
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setTodaysDate();
    const interval = setInterval(() => this.setTodaysDate(), 40 * 1000 * 360);
    this.setState({interval});
  }


  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.state.interval);
  }


  setTodaysDate = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDate: moment(moment(), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss")
        .add(1, "days")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    });


  }
```

Some people also seem to have had some luck by using interval._id:

(Using your initial code)

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  clearInterval(this.interval._id)
}
```

Comment: Ya I've tried the state method to no avail. I just tried it with the ._id method but it also didn't work, it actually shows this.interval._id as undefined when I log it.